# Write ecrypted from input to file with php

Tags: javascript, php

So i have this 2 javascript functions

```
$("#almost-button").click(function(){

    $("#almost-button").html(left_button_almost_state);
    var entered_email=
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'save_email.php',
        data: {email:$("#email-text-box").val()},
        success: redirect(),
        dataType: 'text'
    });

    enable_access_button();

});
```

and

```
$("#access-button").click(function(){

    $("#access-button").html(left_button_submit_state);
    var entered_phone=
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'save_email.php',
        data: {phone:$("#phone-text-box").val()},
        success: redirect(),
        dataType: 'text'
    });

});
```

both point to a php file where i have this

```
        {include('setup/encryption.php');

        $email = encryptPaswd($_POST["email"],getEncryptKey());

        $phone = encryptPaswd($_POST["phone"],getEncryptKey());

        $file = fopen("setup/email.txt","a");

        fwrite($file,date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', time()) . "(".date("l"). "),".  $email .",".  $phone . "\n");

       fclose($file);}
```

So my issue is that i cant write into de file as i want. Nothing is getting saved.

Comment: Can you include text of `redirect()` at Question? Are any errors logged at `console` or server?

Comment: No errors on console, perhaps is not the sytaxis is more the way i orden the code :( the redirect has a text value of a form

Comment: Please fix your title spelling: when you write _ecrypted_, do you mean "decrypted" or "encrypted"?